# Change PHP genereted image with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a following HTML and Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#form_1 input').on('change', function() {
      val = $('input:radio[name=graf]:checked').val();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: ({graf_id: val}),
        url: 'rrd_image.php',
        success: function(data) {
          $('#div_1 img').attr('src', data);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>

<div id="div_1">
  <form id="form_1">
    <input type="radio" name="graf" value="1">Daily
    <input type="radio" name="graf" value="2">Weekly
    <input type="radio" name="graf" value="3">Monthly
  </form>

  <img src="default.png">
</div>
```

And the rrd_image.php:

```
  $graf_id = $_REQUEST['graf_id'];
  $tmpfile = "/tmp/rrd.png";

  // rrd_graph options...

  rrd_graph($tmpfile, $options);

  header( "Content-Type: image/png" );
  header( "Content-Length: " . filesize( $tmpfile ) );

  $fp = fopen( $tmpfile, 'rb' );
  if( $fp ) { fpassthru( $fp ); }
  fclose( $fp );

  exit();
```

The rrd_graph.php itself is working, but when i click one radio-button, the HTML page
do not reload the right PHP generated rrd image.

Comment: Have you tried logging your `$_POST` variables with `print_r($_POST);`?

Comment: Hi, the php script is working, i think the problem is in the ajax function.

Comment: Try replacing `data: ({graf_id: val}),` with `data: {graf_id: val},`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your PHP file is returning an image, not a URL. What I would do is pass your `graf` value, along with a time string, in the query string and then tell JS to load that image instead

```
$(function() {
    $('#form_1 input').on('change', function() {
      var val = $('input:radio[name=graf]:checked').val();
      var time = new Date().getTime();

     $('#div_1 img').attr('src', 'rrd_image.php?graf_id=' + val + '&time=' + time);
    });
  });
```

You don't need AJAX anymore because the `time` parameter will always be different and thus your browser won't cache it.